# Redirect correctly all folders to root site when 403 error occurs

Tags: .htaccess, http, cpanel, http-error

I have my site: `https://stackoverflow.com/` and a subdomain `https://foo.stackoverflow.com/`.

My folder `public_html/foo` has subfolders:

```
public_html/foo/folder_1
public_html/foo/folder_2
public_html/foo/folder_3
```

Now, my `public_html/.htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^403.php$ https://foo.stackoverflow.com/ [R=301]
```

The rule above, works fine when I access `https://stackoverflow.com/foo/folder_1` the page is redirected to `https://foo.stackoverflow.com/` **BUT** when I access `https://foo.stackoverflow.com/folder_1` the page is not redirected and the default 403 error page is displayed.

What can I change in my `public_html/.htaccess` file, to solve this problem?

Please, I want a minimalist solution.

Comment: There is no index file at folder1 right?

Comment: No @mohammed-elhag, the subfolder from my subdomain are for assets from the site.

Comment: paste other rules

Comment: @MohammedElhag this is all rules that I have at this moment.

Comment: This should work only if there is 403 status so make sure that there is no other rule inside folder1 or something that make this happened

Comment: Does your subfolder also have an htaccess file?

Comment: No @starkeen, my intention is stay with all rules in a unique file.